# Android firebase push notification change/Remove small grey icon

Tags: android, firebase

How to remove/change small grey color icon.
[image]

I have this code for generating notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx);
    Notification notification;
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mCtx.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

   // mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION, notification);
```

Comment: You have to create your custom notification for it.

Comment: You should post the code you are using to generate your notification.

Comment: hello @Barns i post my code ....

Comment: The problem (for the developer) is that each phone can (and usually does) have its own standard notification layout. This is good for the user because they can rely on an expected visual experience. The developer can, however, create a custom notification layout, but the `setSmallIcon()` value must be set (I get an error otherwise). You might google "Android Custom Notification Layout" and try some variations, but it remains that `setSmallIcon()` must be set. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove this:

```
setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

as this is the small icon and big one is the large icon `setLargeIcon(..)`

Check this for more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int, int)

> setSmallIcon (int icon)
>   Set the small icon resource, which will be used to represent the notification in the status bar. The platform template for the expanded view will draw this icon in the left, unless a large icon has also been specified, in which case the small icon will be moved to the right-hand side.

You can do this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(dataTitle)
            .setContentText(dataMessage)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);
    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
```

Comment: On all of my test phones (Samsung S7 / MotoG4 / LG Stylo 3) removing `setSmallIcon` results in the error "Invalid notification (no valid small icon)".

Comment: Thanks. My comment was more of the informative nature. I have no issues because I actually use the small icon. I was just pointing out that when I remove `setSmallIcon` I get that error. And your edit is basically the same code I use.

Comment: i remove setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher); then  i get that error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification...

Comment: use the edit I provided @RameshPrajapati, so do not write this `notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)`

Comment: I found solution setSmallIcon(R.drawable.android.xml) android.xml is vactor image then working but i need my ic_launcher logo .xml

Comment: @RameshPrajapati  
use the edit I provided  so do not write this `notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setTicker(title)‌​.setWhen(0)`

Comment: I have try but give me error Invalid notification (no valid small icon)

Comment: @RameshPrajapati here is a way to solve this, basically you need to put transparent (no color) ic_notification.png in mipmap folders and then add that transparent image to setsmallicon

Comment: i have try transparent image but android detect default grey color. i have found another solution i convert my .png image to vactor drawable  and is setSmallIcon() my ic_launcher then work

Answer (score 0):

#### Try This.

## while Generating notification you set your icon like this

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new 
 NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
     notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your icon R.mipmap.ic_launcher is a rectangle. OS is tinting it with white color - that way you have a white rectangle.
The solution is to use custom icon for such case (if you want to keep your launcher icon as is).
I don't know what exactly your icon is, but try to derive your launcher icon to use transparent background (maybe something from https://materialdesignicons.com/ - select one of the icons, click `</>` icon, than "View vector Drawable" - than use it as your small icon for notification).